# Is Django Channels supported in Google App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, websocket, django-channels

I saw that now GAE supports WebSocket... I would know if this include Django Channels (I use the standard GAE, not Flex one).

Fonts (scroll down the page):
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GAE now supports WebSockets in Beta, but only for Flexible Environment by now. From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity#websockets):

> WebSockets are always available to your application without any additional setup.

Websockets should work for any webserver that supports them.

Answer (score 0):

Django Channels uses websockets which is not yet supported by App Engine flex.This mean that you cannot fully use Django Channels on App Engine Flex. We currently working to make websockets available on App Engine Flex.

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#websockets

Comment: and this tutorial? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity

Comment: This is the beta version. I referenced stable App Engine.